# How to display full amount price format in woo-commerce cart page and checkout page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm setting up a WordPress custom theme with woocommerce support. I've come up with a problem display the price format in cart page and checkout page. In the shop page, price display in full like 4,000,000VND
[image]

But it cart page and checkout page, it displays like 4,000KVND. Using the original code from woocommerce cart page and checkout page.

[image]
How do I get rid of the K and display full format instead? If possible, where is the place that I can get this customized? Many thanks.

Comment: please search in your theme files or `function.php` file if your theme is using price filter `woocommerce_price_html`. I think that is what causing the change in price format.

Comment: Absolutely not. The filter is used in woocommerce stock cart and checkout page. Not in my `functions.php` file. That's why I'm looking for a way to control the code of that filter so it can output the format as expected. Thanks @HaiderSaeed